# Self signed certificate in certificate chain with GitHub

Tags: git, github, ssl-certificate

I had a problem where Fortigate's CA was mysteriously removed from Windows 10, and GitHub appears to use Fortigate for SSL, so it basically stopped working, across all applications (including web browsers). I reinstalled the CA, and now it works in browsers etc., but not in git.

I keep getting:

> SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Doing basic things like restarting git, related services etc. does not help. I tried running:

```
GIT_SSL_CAINFO=/path/to/certificate.pem
```

Within git bash itself, it's not verbose so I can't really tell if it does anything (although no error is given, so at least the command runs?).

Is there a way to "refresh" git to recognize the existing CAs installed in Windows, or force it to recognize a specific CA?

Comment: I don't think that `GitHub uses Fortigate for SSL`. You most likely have Fortigate in your organization and this FW uses SSL inspection. Therefore you see Fortigate CA as issuer of github.com.

Comment: That thought hadn't occurred to me, but it makes sense. Is there a way to resolve such issues though regardless of who/what the authority is?

Comment: It may be an issue with [HPKP](http://cookbook.fortinet.com/ssl-public-key-pinning-bulletin/)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, hopefully this solution is not temporary (works so far):

There is an accepted certificate file in Git itself with authorities it accepts, in (change to your Git install dir):

```
%ProgramFiles%\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs
```

It's possible to paste the relevant certificate at the end of: `ca-bundle.crt`. This seems to resolve the problem immediately.